# HTML5 video issue loading videos from C# server

Tags: c#, html, video

I'm having a very-very strange problem with HTML5 video tag. The point is: I need to view video in browser (can't change that, customer wants it to be HTML5). So, i lurked about how it works and found out that it require Range header to work properly and I wrote a little parser to go on with that.
Basicly, everything is in standards, I do return proper headers/bodies/whatever... Here's the list of headers I use

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 206;
if(begin == 0 && end == total)
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", String.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", begin, end, total));
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;");
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
```

As I saw in curl, responses are proper, bytes sending as they should, but the problem is that browsers (for some reason) after sending first reqest with "Range: bytes=0-" (and recieving about 18683 bytes) starting to send requests with "Range: bytes:6865374-" (number is random, it's somwhere near the end of the file) so nothing working because the middle part of file is never asked to be recieved. The server says "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either the thread exit or an application request". I think it's because borwser close connection to the server, but I'm not sure about that.
The great thing is that IE (surprise!) is working fine, except it firstly download whole mp4 file and only then play it.
I already don't know what to do with that, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help. Sometimes browsers or video players request the first couple of bytes and then the last couple of bytes. The most video players, I have seen, requested the last two megabytes of the video. I assume, that the players use these information to determine the actual length of the video. All you have to do, is to send exactly the requested portion of the stream as Partial Content (HTTP Code 206) with the appropriate content length of that portion.

Here is a link which might help: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16

The video players use this for byte based seeking in your video files.

Comment: I've already read that, the response looks correct [screen](https://www.monosnap.com/image/NGo12i52cgAgN0kmsBGgTbqYm/), but only thing that happens is "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either the thread exit or an application request".

Comment: The response code is 200 instead of 206. Did I missed something?

Comment: I am not familiar with C# but I implemented a similar media server with C++. I had to ensure, that the thread which was initially offering the stream was still alive for further requests from this client. This might be somewhat complicated but it may help as you always have the same io identifier for accessing the video file. You can terminate the thread after the client has closed the connection cleanly or a specific timeout occurred.

Comment: I noticed another thing which could cause the error: you specified the last byte index and the end of the stream equally. The byte position of the end is the file size in bytes - 1. So, the end of the stream in your example must rather be 6730168, i.e.: `bytes 6657658-6730168/6730169`